# How to get drag & drop operational in Django

Tags: python, html, django, drag-and-drop

I'm looking to use a drag-n-drop feature for updating a table in my Django model.

I need to be able to drag items (a list of model objects) between 3 baskets and update the item's basket type in the model. My model contains food items and the status of these items. So the food.names will be the items dragged and 3 baskets are the food.status: 'don't have', 'have', 'need to buy'. Just like this example: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/sample/webapis/drag-n-drop-basics/.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
        #div1, #div2, #div3 {
          float: left;
          width: 100px;
          height: 35px;
          margin: 10px;
          padding: 10px;
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
        </style>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
        }
        
        function drag(ev) {
          ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        }
        
        function drop(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
          var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
          ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
        </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
    <p>Drag the items back and forth between the three div elements.</p>
    {% for row in all_food %}
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        {% if row.status_type == 'have'%}
        <ul>
        <li><a href="/" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">{{row}}</a>
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    
    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

The code above comes out as 33 boxes with the items in the for loop scattered among the boxes.

I mainly use Python and don't have much experience working with front end code. What can I try next?

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript library to achieve the drag & drop part? I wonder if using a ready-made plugin would help - although jQuery may be seen by some as old-school, it is pretty simple to get things working.

Comment: (Hmm, it looks like your linked example uses raw JS - do you have the code for that?)